# Not able to start springboot in eclipse, getting BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator'

Tags: spring, maven, web-services, spring-boot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-29 21:39:45.987 ERROR 30192 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/DefaultClockProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.bac.gwbt.cedr.eventnotification.EventNotificationService.EventNotificationServiceApplication.main(EventNotificationServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/DefaultClockProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/DefaultClockProvider
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:135) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar:6.0.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar:6.0.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar:6.0.13.Final]
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276) ~[validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration.defaultValidator(ValidationAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

Comment: what is `defaultValidator`? can you provide related class?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it looks like there's a problem with your Hibernate Validator jar file. It should contain the `DefaultClockProvider` class for when a class definition was not found. Try deleting the jar from Maven's cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: You may want to check the compatibility of the spring-boot version with the tomcat version. Springboot 2.X is only compatible with tomcat 8.5.X. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#third-party-library-upgrades

Answer (score -1):

Looks like org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/DefaultClockProvider not in the classpath. If you are using maven please use below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.14.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator